# Deleting a variable after adding it to a collection

Tags: java, collections, reference

In the following snippet, I want *list* to be a collection of maps. Instead of creating a new HashMap every time, I tried to clear and reuse the previous variable.

```
    List<Map> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String,String> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    aMap.put("fou","bar");
    list.add(aMap);
    aMap.clear();
    aMap.put("big", "bang");
    list.add(aMap);
    System.out.println(list.toString());
```

I was surprised the value inside the list is affected by the *"clear"* operation on the variable aMap, the output is as following:

```
   [{big=bang}, {big=bang}]
```

What's going on here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a tricky question :) Basically the list holds a reference to the object and not a copy of the object. So when you add aMap to the list you add a reference to that Map variable. Then you modify it (and by doing that you modify that reference that you hold in the list) and then you add the same variable to the list again. So now you have two references (or pointers if you prefer) of the same object. That's why you get such result.

Comment: Clear explanation. In the future, I will take precaution when dealing with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already added aMap in the beginning to the list,aMap goes on getting added to the list instead rewrite the code as below:

```
 List<Map> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,String> aMap = new HashMap<>();
aMap.put("fou","bar");
list.add(aMap);
aMap.clear();
aMap.put("big", "bang");
```

// list.add(aMap);> --commented since u have already started adding map values to the array list.

```
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Comment: Actually, what I need is a list like  [{fou=bar}, {big=bang}]. If you commented out the first *add*, only the secondy entry is saved.